# Curl request timing out

Tags: windows, curl

I downloaded Curl and added it to the PATH. Now when I run curl with any URL it simply says failed to connect to a particular IP. Timed out.

[image]

I am using Win7 32 bit. I am on wireless network with IP and DNS setting set to obtain automatically. Any suggestion why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Update :

I see the following in Internet Options

[image]

As you can see I have not selected to use a proxy but atleast I know when that strange IP is coming from. I tried removing it and saving but no use. I am getting same timeout.

Comment: can you access it with your browser ? 
what's strange here is the ip address 10.1.9.20:8080 do you use a  proxy ?

Comment: No I am not using any proxy. Neither can I access it with browser.

Comment: what machine is on 10.1.9.20 ?
what program is running on port 8080 of that machine

Comment: @FredericClose Please see update question. I see where that strange IP is coming from. I used to use it as proxy a year age when I was in college.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of what is the cause or the solution of the above question. But I have figured out a temporary workaround. We can use `--noproxy` option to disable curl using any proxy settings.

Eg. `curl --noproxy * stackoverflow.com`

If anybody encounters this situation and finds out a proper solution please do let me know.